# Can't move my UIScrollView

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiscrollview

I have a content size 1000x10000 and it's center is on the center of the viewcontroller.
I want to push a button for it to turn pages. In the next code I've tried almost any number in the origin.x but nothing changes the scroll view. 
I don't understand the math of it but when I set origin.x=300 and origin.y=100 the view will move up a bit but that's it.

```
CGRect frame=scroller.frame;
frame.origin.x=ANY NUMBER HERE;
frame.origin.y=0;
[scroller scrollRectToVisible:frame animated:YES];
```

How can I set it to move the view from right to left

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

```
[scroller setContentOffset:CGPointMake(300, 0) animated:YES];
```

**[setContentOffset:animated:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIScrollView_Class/Reference/UIScrollView.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIScrollView/contentOffset)** 
*Sets the offset from the content view’s origin that corresponds to the receiver’s origin.*

Comment: Nice one! Any idea how to make the animation slower?

Comment: @MikaStern, Remove the `animated` part. The implement this inside an animation block by specifying time, delay and all.

Comment: Check the animation block used here. You need to add it inside that animation block. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13850786/cant-use-frame-origin-while-settext Add in `animations:^ {
`

Comment: Yea yea, just edited my comment. you wrote the instead of then in your comment so i didn't understood. The animation block you linked to is also mine :)

Comment: @MikaStern, Sorry that was a typo. Tried editing but it didn't allow. I saw that.

Answer (score 0):

You should be creating the UIScrollView's frame to the size of the UIViewController like so:

```
UIScrollView *scroller = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
```

Then set the scrollers CONTENT VIEW to the 1000x10000 size like so:

```
scroller.contentSize = CGSizeMake(1000, 10000);
```

The contentSize is what makes a UIScrollview able to scroll, as long as the contentsize is larger than the scrollers frame.

Comment: my content is much much bigger than the view controller. Still I don't see any scroll when chaging the frame.origin.x

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make it scrollable, then contentSize has to be greater than frame.size, otherwise there isn't space to scroll.
Then ensure that scrollEnabled is set to YES (by default it is, so unless that you've changed it it's already set to YES).