# can't use Frame.origin while setText

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm using the next code to fadeout and scroll up my textfield but I just noticed that when I use something like `[textField setText:@"something"];` or `[textField resignFirstResponder];`   I lose the scrolling up. Any one care to explain why I'm getting this behavior and a posibble workaround.

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                          delay:0.0
                        options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut
                     animations:^ {
                         CGRect Frame = textField.frame;
                         Frame.origin.y=100;
                         textField.frame=Frame;
                        textField.alpha = 0.0;                        
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished) {
                         textField.hidden = YES;
                     }];
    [textField resignFirstResponder];    
}
```

Comment: why do you call resignFirstResponder out of the completion block? it might affect the animation if executed in parallel

Answer (score 0):

You should put the `[textField resignFirstResponder];` into the completion block.